Restrict Spotfire users to read only view and limit data access per user
I'm currently building a reasonably complex Spotfire dashboard, that is intended to be deployed to users as a read only tool via our on-premise server.  I would like to restrict users to view only mode.  At the folder level I can set users to have read only permission to the library, but would like to prevent them from editing particular visualisations and accessing the data canvas.
This feels like it should be a simple option somewhere in the permission control, but I can't work it out.  Any suggestions?
Library permission manager allows control of read only access, but users can still make edits on their own machine but just can't save them to the server.  I'd like to prevent them from making any changes to the dashboard.

I haven't see the read-only functionality on the library, however, you can make it read-only by sharing it via weblink. You can do this by saving your file as a library item and in your library screen, you can click the 3 dots on the right of your saved item and it'll give you the option to "Copy link to item" and you'll select "For Web Clients". They shouldn't be able to make any changes to the dashboard, unless you have visible filters or selection items available. This has worked the best for me and hoping it will help you too.
